# How to remap capslock key to EMACS super using Autohotkey?

Tags: windows, emacs, autohotkey

This site shows how using the registry.
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JonasOster

Comment: According to that page, Emacs on Windows treats the Application key as "super."

Answer (score 4):

[Another page on emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/MovingTheCtrlKey) suggests this in AutoHotKey:

```
#IfWinActive emacs  ; if in emacs
+Capslock::Capslock ; make shift+Caps-Lock the Caps Lock toggle
Capslock::Control   ; make Caps Lock the control button
#IfWinActive        ; end if in emacs
```

Comment: Note that the use of [`#IfWinActive`, the directive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm), is important. [`IfWinActive`, the command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm), won't work. See also ["Remapping Keys and Buttons" in AutoHotkey docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Super does, but I mapped CapsLock to Emacs using this script:

```
CapsLock:: 
  ifwinactive ahk_class Emacs
    send {f16}
return
```

This sends f16 to emacs when emacs is active and capslock is pressed. My keyboard does not have an f16 key, that's why I chose that and in emacs I bound it to some function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f16>") 'some-function)
```

Note that the AHK script does nothing with capslock when emacs is not active. I prefer that, because I consider capslock useless and I press it only accidentally, so it's OK if it does nothing then. You might want to do something else with it if the ifwinactive yields false.

Comment: Need to use it as a modifier. The way its done using super here (global-set-key [(super i)] 'previous-line) 
(global-set-key [(super u)] 'next-line)
I want to type capslock i and get previous-line