# Adding quick-launch bar to Emacs?

Tags: emacs, customization

I want to add a line on top of Emacs editor window, which would display most used buffers - so I would be able to switch between them using hotkeys. Since Emacs is "programmable editor", I assume this should be possible.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tabbar mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode) does something like this, though I recommend checking out [the different buffers switching methods](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers) first, because there are very efficient existing ways to do this.

Comment: Iswitch will do for today. But I still think that 4 key presses (at least - C,x,b, and some letter) are too much to switch between buffers.

Comment: Yes, but who says you have to use the default keybindings? My keybinding rule is the more often you use a binding the shorter it must be. so my buffer switching binding is a single key, because it is a very frequent operation. I bound it to the right control, because I use the left control key, but it can also be bound to other useless keys (capslock, insert, right alt, etc.)

Comment: And how can I do this? Could you paste an example?

Comment: Emacs can't recognize control, capslock, etc. as regular keys, so you have to make the selected key to send a proper keycode, so that in emacs you can bind iswitchb or anything else to it. It depends on your OS how it can be done, on Windows I use Autohotkey for this purpose. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594961/how-to-remap-capslock-key-to-emacs-super-using-autohotkey/8595407#8595407).